# Using parsed input from text file as parameter for new Event

Tags: java, parsing, text, input, variable-assignment

I've working on an assignment that asks me to alter a method in a class to take content from a textfile and use it to create multiple instances of various subclasses of the Event Class. Here is the text file:

```
Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
Event=LightOn,time=2000
Event=WaterOff,time=8000
Event=ThermostatDay,time=10000
Event=Bell,time=9000
Event=WaterOn,time=6000
Event=LightOff,time=4000
Event=Terminate,time=12000
```

The Event=* is the name of the subclass, while time=* is a parameter that is used in the subclass' constructor. The Event class itself is an abstract class and is used for inheritance.

```
public class Restart extends Event {
  Class eventClass;
  String eventInput;
  Long timeDelay;


  public Restart(long delayTime, String filename) {
      super(delayTime);
      eventsFile = filename;
}

    public void action() {
    List<String> examples = Arrays.asList("examples1.txt", "examples2.txt", "examples3.txt", "examples4.txt");
    for (String example : examples) {
        //finding pattern using Regex
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(example);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(eventsFile);
        if (matcher1.find()) {
            File file = new File(example);
            String line;
            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                        new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sc.useDelimiter("\n");
                    //Parsing through text
                    while (sc.hasNext()) {
                        String s = sc.next();
                        String[] array1 = s.split(",");
                        String[] array2 = array1[0].split("=");
                        eventInput = array2[1];
                        String[] array3 = array1[1].split("=");
                        String timeInput = array3[1];

                        try {
                            eventClass = Class.forName(eventInput);
                            timeDelay = Long.parseLong(timeInput);


                            try {

                            addEvent(new eventClass(timeDelay));
                            }
                            //catch block
                            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                            System.out.println("No Such Method Error");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("error");
                            }

                       //catch block     
                       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Unable to locate Class");
                       } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Illegal Acces Exception"); 
                       } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Instantiation Exception");
                       }



                    }
                }
                //Close bufferedReader
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            //catch block
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Unable to open file '" +
                                file + "'");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


            break;
        }
        //if input match is not found
        else {
            System.out.println("No Match Found");}

    }
}
```

I seem to be able to parse fine, and find the strings i'm looking for, but I'm not able to use eventInput which I've pulled from the text file as a parameter to create a new event.

```
eventClass = Class.forName(eventInput);
```

doesn't seem to be turning my string into an acceptable parameter either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I know I'm probably missing something key here, but I've been staring at it too long that it seems like a lost cause.

Here is the Event class:

```
public abstract class Event {
private long eventTime;
protected final long delayTime;
public Event(long delayTime) {
  this.delayTime = delayTime;
  start();
}
public void start() { // Allows restarting
  eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayTime;
}
public boolean ready() {
  return System.currentTimeMillis() >= eventTime;
}
public abstract void action();
} ///:~
```

Comment: Step 1: Visit the [help] and especially read [ask].  Step 2: [edit] your post and explain in detail what you mean by _"Using Class.forname doesn't seem to be working either"_ -- without a clear explanation of what is not working you are not likely to get much help.

Comment: @JimGarrison I added more details and clarity, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how reflection works. Once you have a `Class` object (the output from `Class.forName()`, you have to find the appropriate constructor with

```
Constructor<T> constructor = eventClass.getConstructor(parameter types)
```

and then create a new instance with

```
constructor.newInstance(parameters);
```

For a no-arg constructor there's a shortcut

```
eventClass.newInstance();
```

I strongly suggest you read the tutorials on reflection before proceeding.

Comment: I included this to my answer, however it seems like it's getting stuck in the try block where I'm using Class.Forname(). I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException, I've double checked I have the fully qualified name and the parsed string that I'm using doesn't have any extra characters before/after. Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: Your question still does not make any sense.  `new eventClass(timeDelay)` is not valid Java as `eventClass` is not the literal name of a class.  You cannot use a variable of type `Class` in this manner. Please re-read my answer in this context.